# How to recursively get absolute url from parent instance(s)?

Tags: python, django, resolveurl

I have a page model that contains instance of itself as possible parent page. So every page can be child of another page. What I would like to do is get the absolute url to give me link that is structured according to its parent architecture. So let's say I have a Page AAA with child BBB, which itself has a child CCC. The url of last child would be mysite.com/AAA/BBB/CCC. I've played around and figured a recursive method that would work for me, however I hit a brick wall on resolving the urls.

**models.py**

```
class Page {
     ...
     parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
     ....

     def get_parent_path(self, list=None):

          parenturl = []

          if list is not None:
              parenturl = list

          if self.parent is not None:
              parenturl.insert(0,self.parent.slug)
              return self.parent.get_parent_path(parenturl)

          return parenturl

     def get_absolute_url(self):

          path = ''

          if self.parent is not None:
               parentlisting = self.get_parent_path()
               for parent in parentlisting:
                    path = path + parent + '/'

          path = path + self.slug;

          return reverse("pages:details", kwargs={"path": path, "slug": self.slug})
```

**urls.py**

```
     url(r'^(?P<path>.+)(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.page, name='details'),
```

Testing it, showed me that path I get gives the correct parental part of the path. But resolving urls doesn't seem to work and I'm thinking it has something to do with reverse and/or regex. Using any page link, even where 404 should be, will now give me type error.

```
TypeError at /###/###/

page() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

**views.py**

```
def page(request, slug):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug)

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "page": instance,
    }

    return render(request, "page.html", context)
```

Comment: Please, post your `views.page` view.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with your get_absolute_url method, or any of the code you've posted.

Comment: @vishes_shell posted views in update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all your `page` view is not accepting `path` argument.

You need to change `def page(request, slug):` to `def page(request, slug, path):`. Also you need to rethink if you need that param in your url and in your view, because you don't use it.

**Further part might not be relevant**

And one more thing, you forgot to put `/` between params in url

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.+)(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.page, name='details'),
```

should be

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.page, name='details')
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the problem. `path` already adds / after each parent.

Comment: Adding the path to views worked for me. However for some reason it would show 404 pages for top parents (mysite.com/AAA) while for all it's children it worked. I had to create additional line in urlpattern, one for top parent pages and one for children pages.
Also what do you mean I need to rethink if I need the path parameter? I'm using it to access page CCC by going to mysite.com/AAA/BBB/CCC instead of mysite.com/CCC. I'm new to django so I may be missing something, is there a more efficient way to get the absolute url as intended here?

Comment: @Ablivion the thing was: you were trying to get instance without any `path` argument, just with slug. So that's why i thought that you don't need `path` argument. However, i took a closer look and you've got quite complicated login in `get_absolute_url()`, but you don't apply this logic as you are retrieving records, you just getting object with provided `slug`. And i'm honestly don't think that's not a great idea to construct url like you're doing in `get_absolute_url().

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only way I know how to construct path for now. I'm open to any suggestions for improving it.